# Creating a Sharepoint list and assigning scores to each answer to be totaled at the end

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have created a list in sharepoint on office 365. However, the users would like the list to calculate a weighted total based off of answers.

**For example:**

Did the contractor do X,Y,Z?
Answer 1
Answer 2
Answer 3

Did the contractor submit for x,y,x?

Answer 1  Answer 2 Answer 3

*Is it then possible to go ahead and in each column of the list say if answer 1 then score = 1 if option 2 then score = 2. And do that for each question. And then have the total score populate in a field at the end of the list?*

Answer (score 0):

- Option1: you can use workflow to update the score column on the basis of answer.
- Option2: you can make score as a calculated column which will be updated once item created according to the condition.

For showing the sum please refer this url:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30317.sharepoint-2013-displaying-sum-for-calculated-column-in-a-list-view-using-jslink.aspx